# Reference default path in powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, path

Is there a way to call the system path if the path has been changed in the current terminal? i.e.:

```
$env:Path = "C:\some new path"   
#some coding that requires a different path set up
$env:Path = $defaultPath #would have to define $defaultPath by calling the system default path
```

Comment: [1] replacing the environment path for a one-off use is ... peculiar & dangerous. do not do that if you can avoid it. [*grin*] ///// [2] if you need to **_modify or add to_** the env-path, then do that, don't REPLACE it with a shortened path. ///// [3] if you MUST replace the env-path with another & need to access the old path later ... save the old path & restore it as needed. ///// [4] a far safer method would be to start a new session, destroy the env-path in that session, work there, and then exit that session ... continuing your work in the original session.

Comment: That is exactly what this does. It does not change the system path, only the path in that terminal session

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I just figured out that you can do that. Thanks!

Comment: @user14894283 - that is not what you implied [*grin*] you said you wanted to reference the default path after you had replaced it. the only way to do that is to restore it since the apps that use the path are not aware of any other way to do what the OS does with the `Path` env-var. ///// **_the only 2 ways to to that are [A] to do things as intended ... add to the path in the current session. [B] swap them back-n-forth as needed._** the 2nd of those is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at my if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to reload the `$env:PATH` environment variable from the registry, as *future* sessions would see it (assuming no further relevant registry updates are made).

If your current session hasn't made any relevant registry updates, this is the same as getting the value that was in effect on session startup - barring any dynamic additions via a [`$PROFILE` script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#profile):

```
$env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'),
            [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -join ';'
```

Note:

- A process' effective `$env:PATH` value is a *composite* value of a *machine-level* and a *user-level* registry entry, with the machine-level definition taking precedence, as reflected in the two .NET API calls above.

  - Note that the underlying registry locations - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHIN\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` - are `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry values, i.e. they may be defined in terms of *other* environment variables, such as `%SystemRoot%` and `%ProgramFiles%`.
  - Both the .NET API calls above - using [`[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable) - and PowerShell's [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) and [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) cmdlets *expand* (interpolate) such references and return *verbatim* paths - which is what new processes see by default too.
- Given the above, the only way to *robustly* retrieve the value that was in effect at session startup time is to *save it in a variable* at startup time.

Comment: I don't want it to save. It's specific so that I run the command and it changes the path for the current terminal

Comment: Your response is beyond my knowledge level. I'll have to do some reading. For the time being, could you take a look at my if statement. I think I need a flag/tracking variable but I dont quite understand those yet

Comment: @user14894283, I don't understand what you mean by _to save_. The call in this answer only _retrieves_ definitions from the registry, in a manner that mimics what new processes will see in `$env:PATH` and - if no change was made to the relevant registry locations since session startup -  what your session originally saw (before potential modification via `$PROFILE`).

Comment: @user14894283, please ask _follow-up_ questions neither (a) via your original question post, nor (b) via _answer_ posts - answer posts should only be used for actual answers to the question at hand. Either use comments to ask for minor clarifications, or create a _new_ question post.

Comment: My post was edited by an admin because I did that and I was told to use comments today]. Which is it?

Comment: What is the difference between that and $env:path = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name PATH).Path

Comment: @user14894283: what you used wasn't a _comment_ but an _answer_ post. Please note that, in general, this site isn't a chat forum; instead, its strength comes from focused, well-defined questions and similarly focused answers. That's what provides the most benefit to future readers.

Comment: @user14894283, as for the difference: please see the comment I just posted on Abraham's answer.

Comment: Not that it matters (*as it may be different on your machine*), placing `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')` before the call to *Computer* doesn't join the two strings with a double semicolon: `.\AppData\..\WindowsApps;;`. Just creates an extra empty path which shouldn't affect anything lol just bothered me when I did it using `Get-ItemPropertyValue`.

Comment: @Abraham, the command above doesn't try to prevent double `;;`, for brevity, but you certainly could. Do note that the `'Machine'` value _must come first_ in order to mimic what the system itself does: the order of the entries matters, and machine-level definitions take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

It's still stored in the registry so you can just query it:

- Located: `HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

```sh
$key = "HKCU:\Environment",
       "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
       
(Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $key -Name Path) -Join ';'
```

Querying the key using `Get-ItemPropertyValue` (*as suggested by [Mklement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)*) will give you just the *property's* value.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the value stored as?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, could you help me figure out why my if then statements are not working?

Comment: @user14894283, what isn't working?